# Magento 2 Search showing 404 Not Found

Tags: php, magento, magento2

Hello I'm Magento 2 beginner developer.

I developed simple store utilizing Magento 2 & Supro Theme.
the problem that in front-end home page. when user click on search icon and enter any term it always shows 404 Not Found page.

I've tried the flowing server commands:

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

but nothing changed. can you help me...

Comment: First call `bin/magento indexer:reset` after that `bin/magento indexer:reindex`. Can you paste the output from `bin/magento indexer:status`?

Comment: Thanx @AdamS. I've tried your arranging but I got the same results.
the output is as following:

"Catalog Product Rule, Catalog Rule Product, Catalog Search, Category Products, Customer Grid, Design Config Grid, Google Product Feed, Google Product Removal Feed, Inventory, Product Categories, Product EAV, Product Price, Stock"

all are Ready - Update on Save